# Cubic lattice representation of a solid torus knot using the surface as a boundary

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, surfaces

For physics simulation reasons, I would like to respresent a solid torus knot as a collection of integer points sat on a cubic lattice.

If I were to do this using a sphere, I would do this by saying any point in the sphere must satisfy

$\sqrt{(x-x_c)^2 + (y-y_c)^2 + (z-z_c)^2} \leq r$

However, I now need to do this for a trefoil (and ideally any torus knot).

To generate the surface of a solid trefoil, I emulated the technique used in this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91444/what-is-parameterization-of-the-trefoil-knot-surface-in-r%C2%B3).

Briefly, I find the normal and binormal of the torus knot, then construct the equation

$r(\theta,\alpha) = \gamma(\theta) + c \sin(\alpha)\hat{\textbf{n}}(\theta) + c \cos(\alpha)\hat{\textbf{b}}_n(\theta)$

where $\gamma(\theta)$ is the [path of the torus knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot) using the linked parameterisation, and c is the radius of the "rope". If I understand this correctly, this gives me the surface of a solid torus.

However, I now need to determine if a given coordinate on my cubic lattice exists inside the knot, so I can construct the solid volume. At this point I reach the limits of my mathematical knowledge.

[In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019260/how-can-you-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-parametric-2d-manifold) it is suggested this can be achieved by the Stokes-Carten theorem. However, after having sat down and looked at how this works, I have realised 8 years of not touching this has caused me to lose all knowledge of how to even begin this problem.

Any guidance, or ideally a solution, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps calculate the minimum distance from a given lattice point $p$ to the path, and declare $p$ inside if that distance is $\le$ the radius of the rope.

Comment: If you have a grid diagram presentation of a link, you can obtain a cubic lattice presentation as follows: for each dot at (m,n) in the diagram, your cubic lattice will have a vertex at (m,n,1) and (m,n,0), and an edge connecting them. If you have dots (m,n) and (m',n) in the same row, add an edge connecting (m,n,0) and (m', n, 0), while if you have dots (m, n) and (m, n') in the same column, add an edge connecting (m,n,1) and (m, n', 1). This gives the desired presentation.

Comment: Such a grid diagram is presented in Exercise 3.1.5 here https://web.math.princeton.edu/~petero/GridHomologyBook.pdf

Comment: For the solid version you could thicken this by tripling all terms I wrote in the previous paragraph and then taking the set of integer lattice points of distance 1 to the given set